# how to use optgroup with array in blade in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

how to use optgroup with array in blade in laravel 5.3?

I use [select2](https://select2.github.io/) in my project.

For Example:

```
<select class="form-control select2">
  <optgroup label="Top Airport">
    <option value="MHD">Mashhad</option>
    <option value="THR">Tehran</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="All Airport">
    <option value="MHD">Mashhad</option>
    <option value="THR">Tehran</option>
    <option value="LON">London</option>
    .
    .
    .
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

In `Controller`:

```
public function index()
{
    $airport = Airport::where('status', 1)->pluck('city', 'iata');
    return view($this -> path_site_theme() . '.home.index', ['airport' => $airport]);
}
```

In `index.blade.php`:

```
{{ Form::select('from', ['Top Airport' => ['MHD', 'Mashhad', 'THR' => 'Tehran'], 'All Airport' => $airport], null, ['class' => 'form-control select2']) }}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is Form::select() not giving you the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pluck` method return an instance of `Collection` while the `Form::select()` expects an array. You can chain `toArray()` method on pluck to make it work.

```
$airport = Airport::where('status', 1)->pluck('city', 'iata')->toArray();
```

Or better, use coalescing operator if you are using PHP7. It will never fail even if there's no active airports in database which happens a lot with `toArray()` when it tries to convert null into an array.

```
$airport = Airport::where('status', 1)->pluck('city', 'iata')->toArray() ?? [];
```